# How do I give a user access to all repositories in gitolite?

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a certain user (backup) that regularly clones/fetches all the repositories in our gitolite system.  I have to manually add

```
 R = backup
```

to every single repo I have.  Is there an easier way to give this user access to every single repo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
repo    @all
  R     = backup
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that if, for some reason, you need to exclude a repo from user '`backup`' access, you can add a deny rule:

```
repo gitolite-admin
    -   =   backup
    option deny-rules = 1

repo @all
    R   =   backup
```

Here, you wouldn't backup the main `gitolite-admin` repo, for instance.

See [rules of accumulation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html#rule-accum).